# Codeigniter 4, как создать расширение

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter 4, как создать расширение controller? В Codeigniter 3 есть папка core - и там можно сделать расширение базового контроллера.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял вы хотите, реализовать что-то типа Public и Admin контроллеры?
В этом случае создайте в **application/Controllers/** контроллер:

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class PublicController extends Controller
{
    //some public logic
}
```

И от него наследуйтесь:

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

class Home extends PublicController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать